# Biztalk BTAHL7 batching - cannot start a Batch process

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, hl7, biztalk-2020, btahl7

We installed Biztalk 2020 and its HL7 accelarator.  I'm trying to setup a HL7 batching based on this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/accelerator-hl7/part-3-create-batch-scenario) from Microsoft.

First I made sure I started the Batch Orchestration and its receive port from within Biztalk Application 1

[image]

[image]

Next I created a party call Test and assign it a Send Port.

[image]

[image]

After Restart the Biztalk host instance to make sure the changes are applied, I brought up the BTAHL7 Configuration Explorer and go to the "Test" party to start the HL7 batching.

[image]

whenever I start a batch, I keep getting error on the BatchControlPort.

[image]

[image]

The way I think this implies to me is the BatchOrchestration.Orchestration_1 orchestration received a signal to tell it to start a batching process for the party Test but since it found no subscribed send/receive port, it stops right away and display the error.

I modified my send port to only subscribed to the BTAHL7MessageType == OutboundBatch, meaning this port is listening to any batching process that finished so I'm kinda baffle that Biztalk keeps telling me there is no subscriber.

[image]

Based on what you see me done so far, do you see I miss any steps? I'm at a point where I cannot get a batching process started, I don't even touch any message to be batched yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when you start a party's batching via the BTAHL7 Configuration Explorer, it generates a small HL7 message and put it into the directory where the receive port BatchControlLocation is monitoring, in the case of Biztalk 2020 it is under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Accelerator for HL7\CreateBatchFileDrop*.*

This receive port is automatically created by the Biztalk Accelerator installation but by default it is set to PassThroughReceive which does not do anything to read HL7 format message.

[image]

Upon me changing the receive pipeline to BTAHL72XReceivePipeline then now it can read that trigger HL7 format message and I can now see my newly created batch process for party Test under the dehydrated orchestration list.

[image]